# how to get rid of the border-bottom by css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

how to get rid of the border-bottom which under **test** text in the **li** when the mouse hover on the **test** text by css?

the html :

```
     <div class="rank">
         <ul>
            <li class="tab1 active">test</li>
            <li class="tab2">one</li> 
         </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="content">....</div>
```

my style(it's doesn't get rid of the bottom under test text):

```
.active{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
rank ul li{
float:left;
border:1px solid #D5D5D5;
border-bottom:none;
}

.content{
clear:both;
border-top:1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

ps: why when i use `overflow:hidden` to `rank` div, it can prevent the float to the `content` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zhuanzhou; may be you have to play with `margin` `padding` 
**for example**

```
.rank ul{
    border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
.active{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
padding-bottom:1px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.rank ul li{
float:left;
border:1px solid #D5D5D5;
border-bottom:none;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.content{
clear:both;
border-top:1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

check live demo http://jsfiddle.net/PBBED/

*NOTE*:in my example i am using `clear:both` instead of `overflow:hidden` for `clear floated` child element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.active{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
ul li{
    display:inline;
}
li{
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
li:hover{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.content{
clear:both;
border-top:1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove line 7 in your css then start a new selector using the css psuedo class :hover at the end

```
rank ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Although, older browser will disregard that unless it is on an a tag.